# Is there a way to install pip and zlib-devel on RHEL 5.7 without Red Hat entitlement?

Tags: redhat, installation

I'm moving out of a old RHEL 5.7 server for a client and need to run a migration script in python to send all data to our new storage in Azure.

To install azure cli tools i need pip but I'm unable to install pip since there's no zlib-devel on the machine.

Normally I would just install it through the package manager but the client doesn't have an active subscription and entitlement with Red Hat so the packager manager get stuck saying I need to login in to red hat and buy more licenses.

Can I download zlib-devel from somewhere and make instal it? If so, where do I look? (I found some locations but haven't worked a lot with Enterprise Linux so I'm not sure what to pick).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the CentOS versions from http://vault.centos.org/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/

Assuming 64-bit OS...

zlib-devel: http://vault.centos.org/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/zlib-devel-1.2.3-4.el5.x86_64.rpm

So in this case, you can likely:

```
# rpm -ivh http://vault.centos.org/5.7/os/x86_64/CentOS/zlib-devel-1.2.3-4.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: I am getting error `warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.UiXDCQ: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID e8562897: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        zlib = 1.2.3 is needed by zlib-devel-1.2.3-4.el5.x86_64`